# How to change order of sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, summation-method

I need change  the summation order in the double sum
$$
S_{m,n}=\sum_{j=0}^m \sum_{k=0}^n a_{j,k} x^{j-k} B_{m+n-j-k},
$$
to  separate $B$ and get  somethink like to
$$
S_{m,n}=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n} \left(  \sum_{k=0}^* **** \right) B_{s}.
$$
I tried to introduce new variable $m+n-j-k=s$  but the formal  expression
$$
\sum_{s=0}^{m+n} \left(  \sum_{k=0}^n  a_{m+n-s-k,k} x^{m+n-s-2k} \right) B_{s}.
$$
is differ from  $S_{m,n}.$

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your sum is fine if you adopt a convention that $a_{j,k} = 0$ whenever $(j,k) \not \in (0\cdots m, 0 \cdots n)$.

To see this more formally, allow suffices $(j,k) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ with the convention just stated.  Then map $(j,k)$ to $(r,s)$ by

$$(j,k) \mapsto (k,m+n-(j+k)).$$

The mapping is easily seen to be one to one and surjective because $(r,s) \mapsto (m+n-(r+s), r) $ provides an inverse.  Then

\begin{align}
S_{m,n} &= \sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^n a_{j,k}~ x^{j-k} ~B_{m+n-(j+k)} \\
&= \sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_{j,k} ~ x^{j-k} ~ B_{m+n-(j+k)} \\
&= \sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{r=\infty}^{\infty} a_{m+n-(s+r),r}~x^{m+n-s-2r} ~ B_s
\end{align}

where the extension of suffices to formally infinite sums is legitimate because all terms except a finite number are zero.  We can now reduce back to a finite sum.  When $r < 0$ or $r > n$ the coefficients $a_{m+n-(s+r),r}$ are zero;  and it then also follows, when $ s < 0$ or $s > m+n $ the coefficients are again zero.  Therefore we obtain

$$ S_{m,n} = \sum_{s=0}^{m+n} \sum_{r=0}^n a_{m+n-(s+r),r}~ x^{m+n-s-2r}~B_s$$
which is exactly the sum you obtained.  Moreover, when $r > n$ the terms are zero so the upper limit could also be taken as $m+n$ if you prefer.

---

Appendix:  This picture illustrates the different sums:  first by rows then columns (or vice versa) then by diagonals, with three sections depending on the sizes of $j$ and $k$ and finally the method used above where additional dummy $a_{j,k} = 0$ are added.

[image: Illustration of different approaches to the sums]

Comment: No, for $m=1,n=2$ we have $$S_{1,2}={\frac {a_{{1,2}}{ B}_{{0}}}{x}}+ \left( {\frac {a_{{0,2}}}{{x}^{2
}}}+a_{{1,1}} \right) { B}_{{1}}+ \left( {\frac {a_{{0,1}}}{x}}+a_
{{1,0}}x \right) { B}_{{2}}+a_{{0,0}}{ B}_{{3}}
$$  but yours formula gives $$\left( a_{{3,0}}{x}^{3}+a_{{2,1}}x+{\frac {a_{{1,2}}}{x}} \right) { B}_{{0}}+ \left( {\frac {a_{{0,2}}}{{x}^{2}}}+a_{{1,1}}+a_{{2,0}}
{x}^{2} \right) { B}_{{1}}+ \left( a_{{1,0}}x+{\frac {a_{{0,1}}}{x
}} \right) { B}_{{2}}+ a_{{0,0}}  { B}_{{3}}
$$

Comment: @Leox Except I have adopted the convention $a_{3,0} = 0 a_{2,1} = a_{2,0} = 0$.  With this proviso, the additional terms are all zero and the two sums agree.

Comment: @Leox  If you prefer to leave the terms $a_{j,k}$ unaltered, instead introduce an indicator function $\xi_{j,k}$ which takes the value $1$ when $0 \leqslant j \leqslant m$ and $0 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, otherwise zero.

Comment: Sorry, now understood

Comment: Thanks for the pictures!

Comment: one more question - I think that the $n$ and $m$ are eqivalent but if I replace  the upper bound in the second sum by $m$ I get again wrong formula

Comment: The $n$ is tied to the second suffix for $a$, so if you want to swap roles you need to do more than simply substitute one for the other.  If you do swap, you would need (using my $r$ and $s$ make $r$ the first suffix for $a$ and the second has to be $m+n-(s+r)$.  The power of $s$ in terms of $s$ and $r$ then has opposite sign, $2r+s - (m+n)$.  You still need the convention that $a_{j,k}$ is zero for $j$ and $k$ outside the original domain.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: WA Don Ok, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the $(j,k)$ plane, the domain of the summation is an axis-aligned rectangle. Then the locus of constant $s=m+n-j-k$ is a pencil of parallel line segments slanted by $-45°$, which meet the rectangle boundaries in three different ways: from $k=n$ to $j=m$, from $j=0$ to $j=m$ and from $j=0$ to $k=0$. Hence you can't escape decomposing the sum in three different expressions (two triangles and a parallelogram).

Comment: Unless you extend the range of the $a_{i,j}$ and make them zero where not already defined... then you can change the sum order and still work with a rectangle.  You have more terms, many being zero, but a simple expression, right?

Comment: @WADon: I expected this comment. IMO, the simplification is fictive, you just drop some relevant information. When it comes to truly evaluating the sum, you will have to somehow restrict the range of summation of one of the indexes or introduce some indicator function. In the same vein, you could even use sums from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ for all indexes and assume zeroes where required.

Comment: Quite so, a convenient shorthand, also used from time to time when dealing with integrals over a non rectangular domain.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I've added an answer in the same line. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer in the same line as the answer of @YvesDaoust. In order to change the summation to the wanted form $S_{m,n}=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n} \left(  \sum_{k=0}^* **** \right) B_{s}$ we sum up the terms corresponding to the example graphic below:

[image]

> Assuming WLOG $m\leq n$ we  obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_{m,n}}&=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^na_{j,k}x^{j-k}B_{m+n-j-k}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^na_{m-j,n-k}x^{m-n-j+k}B_{j+k}\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\sum_{s=0}^{m-1}\sum_{k=0}^s+\sum_{s=m}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^m+\sum_{s=n+1}^{m+n}\sum_{k=s-n}^m\right)
> a_{m-s-k,n-k}x^{m-n-s+2k}B_s}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of summation in both, the inner sum ($j\to m-j$) and the outer sum ($k\to n-k$), which gives a somewhat more convenient representation of $B_{q}$.
- In (2) we set $s=j+k$ and since $0\leq j\leq m$ and $0\leq k\leq n$ we have $0\leq s=j+k\leq m+n$. We get three inner sums according to the three regions in the graphic.

**Note:** The three inner sums in (2) might look somewhat complicated, but this is rather an advantage.

- Here we have a plain rearrangement of the $(m+1)(n+1)$ terms of $S_{m,n}$ resulting in the wanted form.
- The three inner sums reflect the structure of summation.
- We do not need bookkeeping of additional zero-valued variables and their regions when doing further calculations.

Comment: Great as allways! Please see my new question about change order in a sum. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745135/change-summation-order

Comment: @Leox: Many thanks for your nice comment. I've added an answer.